# Multer doesn't save the file to the web server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

Hey I'm trying to use multer to save files on the web server but it doesn't work.

I tried every answer on stack overflow but nothing solves it. No error it just doesn't work. I tried running it both locally and on Openshift.

Here's the relevant lines from my code.
Client side:

```html
<form id="upload_form" method="POST" action="/submit_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
  <input type="file" id="software" name="software"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Server side:

```js
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended = true }));
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "uploads/",
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname);
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: { fieldSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 } }).single("software");
app.post("/submit_upload", upload, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); // is alright
    console.log(req.file); // undefined
}
app.listen(8080, function() { console.log("started"); });
```

Comment: In the form, you use the post method but your endpoint is the "get" endpoint. Why?

Comment: it's a mistake from when I copied the code to stack overflow it should be post

Comment: Please, change it to "post".